# Unable to start program outside Windows folder

Tags: powershell, process

I'm trying to control an external program that I call inside PowerShell and if this program takes more than 10s, for example, I want to terminate it. How can I accomplish that?

I have searched, but what I found was the following code. I can use this code to call `calc.exe` for example, and terminate it after a specific amount of time, but I can't call another program that is not from system32 or Windows folder. Why?

```psh
$ps = New-Object diagnostics.processstartinfo
$ps.FileName='c:\folder\program.exe'
$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($ps)
$p.WaitForExit(10000)
$p.Kill()
```

Comment: I am not seeing a problem with this code at all. I was able to start an application from my Downloads folder without a problem and it worked as expected. Give us the full path of the executable you're trying to start so maybe we can spot problems in it, and give us the error message you're receiving.

Comment: I'm trying to run a program on the 'C:\teste\bin' folder, I made a copy of calc.exe to this folder to make a test, and it's not working. I got no error messages when I execute the code. The Powershell ISE is being run as Administrator.

Comment: @LeandroChiesa Did you copy just `calc.exe`? For me, it also does not work, if I copy just `calc.exe` to different directory and try to run it. But if I replace `c:\folder\program.exe` in your code to `C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe`, then it works without any problems.

Comment: @PetSerAl Yes, I just copied calc.exe, but it is not working, I noticed that when I execute on system folders like "Windows", "System32" or other like that the program runs fine, but when I run on a different folder, the program is launched but it closes immediately.

Comment: "Calculator" is not a single self-contained `calc.exe` file, so it will not run if you copy just `calc.exe` to other folder. But it is not because it is outside of `System32` folder, but because it can not find required files to run.

Comment: Hmm that would be an explanation for this behavior @PetSerAl, I'm going to try something different and check the results.

Answer (score 0):

A very likely problem is that the program you are trying to run is an x86 application and you are trying to run it from powershell x64. This will not work and as far as I remember powershell will not even tell you why.

Instead you need to run the x86 version. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847733.aspx

Comment: I does not have any problem in running 32-bit program from 64-bit PowerShell prompt. Nor 64-bit program from 32-bit PowerShell prompt.

Comment: I just tried to run the code on the 32-bit Powershell, but it didn't work out.